# PHP include() function generate error for xml

Tags: php, xml, include

Need help.

I create a php file that generate xml for displaying marker in google map. It works fine when I open it directly like `dir://file.php` and the xml file shown as the result.

But when I open it by using include function like : **include ('file.php');** as I need in my website structure, it getting error :

```
    XML Parsing Error: mismatched tag.....
```

Why php `include` function generated this error?

Comment: ... did you actually check the XML for a mismatched tag?

Comment: yes, but it works well when I call directly it show the xml structure. As you can see these links :

Comment: yes, but it works well when I call directly it show the xml structure. As you can see these links for open the index.php : http://giantestate.com/plugins/property-map/index.php and show the map_process.php that call by index.php (ajax content) http://giantestate.com/plugins/property-map/map_process.php. The problem occurred when I call the index file from the main index using include('/plugins/property-map/index.php').

Answer (score 0):

Because you **shouldn't** include a file that doesn't contain PHP code.

use `readfile()` instead

Answer (score 0):

dont use include , use `file_get_content()`

Comment: Perhaps you can elaborate on the reason? This makes it easier to understand your answer.

Comment: But I still dont know how to make it. Maybe I can explain more detail that I have two file index.php and map_process.php. The index file containing header link and ajax code underneath, and the map_process.php containing a php script to generate xml. This index.php use $.get("map_process.php", function (data) {..} to read the xml. What I need is how to open index.php among the other files within the whole my web structure, while using php include function its doesn't work as I use include ('dir/index.php').